# UTF-16 character encoding issue with FireFox (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, unicode, encoding, mozilla

I'm having a similar issue to the one posted in the following stackoverflow question:
[UTF-16 character encoding issue with FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724916/utf-16-character-encoding-issue-with-firefox)
- But in my case is with JSON documents instead of XML.

I have a correctly encoded (with its BOM) UTF-16 JSON text file. I'm retrieving this text content by means of a javascript httpXmlRequest, and then using the command ***window.JSON.parse*** to parse the response text to a javascript object. It works for browsers Chrome and Explorer, but window.JSON.parse crashes with Mozilla.

I probably will change the file encoding to UTF-8, but really I'm a little bit confused, as it looks like either I'm doing something unproperly, or either some browsers are being too tollerant or not having a standard behaviour.

If someone can shed some light regarding to this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I ended up changing encoding to UTF-8 and Mozilla started working.

Comment: Good idea, why would one want UTF-16 anywhere. utf8everywhere.org